# Create New User Google Workspace PHP api

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client

I am little new in PHP and Google Workspace. I am trying to create new user in my workspace. I have my code like this

```
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json");
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject($workspace_admin_email);
$client->setApplicationName("Quickstart");
$client->setScopes(["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user"]);
$service = new Directory($client);

$optParams = array(
        'customer' => 'my_customer',
        'maxResults' => 500,
        'orderBy' => 'email',
    );
    $results = $service->users->listUsers($optParams);
```

Its working fine for get all users from my workspace but I do not know how I can create new user

They have not any PHP sample for same. They have given rest API documentation for javascript here

```
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/insert
```

But I am using PHP in all places so I want do it with PHP. Let me know if anyone here can help me for same

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [user insert](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/insert) method.

```
//create user
$user = new Google_Service_Directory_User();
$name = new Google_Service_Directory_UserName();
// SET THE ATTRIBUTES
$name->setGivenName('John');
$name->setFamilyName('Smith');
$user->setName($name);
$user->setHashFunction("MD5");
$user->setPrimaryEmail("john.smith@yourdomain.com");
$user->setPassword(hash("md5","Horse"));


try 
{ 
    $createUserResult = $service -> users -> insert($user); 
    var_dump($createUserResult); 
}
```